# Is there any good tutorial on building an activex control using visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, activex

I need to develop an ActiveX control that can read CD's and USB drives.

Is there a good tutorial on developing sucha a control in visual studio using C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973200.aspx)
[MSMVPS](http://msmvps.com/blogs/pauldomag/archive/2006/08/16/107758.aspx)
[C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dsandor/ActiveXInNet11102005040748AM/ActiveXInNet.aspx)

If you would like to get a list of drives and DoWork with the Removable and CDRom drives:

```
DriveInfo[] ListDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListDrives)
{
    if (Drive.DriveType.Removable || Drive.DriveType.CDRom)
    {
    //DoWork
    }    
}
```

Then you can check if what you would like to read exists and then read it.

Comment: I sense the first 3 hits on Google when you typed in "building an activex control using visual studio". LMGTFY